# Flex: binding a function call

Tags: actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, binding, actionscript

I've been out of Flex development for a while, and I'm trying to understand some code I'm coming across.  I've included an example below, but the gist of it is, why are they using {} in the event handler?  Isn't that binding?  What's it binding for?

In the example below, what's the difference between using `anEvent="{doSomething(event)}"` and using `anEvent="doSomething(event)"`?

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private static function doSomething(e:CustomEvent):void {
            trace("something happens here");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<myComponents:CustomComponent
    anEvent="{doSomething(event)}"
/>


// custom component definition
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:UIComponent 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="100%" 
    height="100%">


    <mx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="anEvent", type="com.mydomain.CustomEvent")]
    </mx:Metadata>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function test():void
            {
                var e:Customevent = new CustomEvent("custom_event_name");
                dispatchEvent(e);
            }

            /** @inheritDoc **/
            override protected function commitProperties():void
            {
                super.commitProperties();
                test();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:UIComponent>
```

Comment: Please see my answer below and please accept it if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference in the two approaches in your case here. Method binding is helpful when you want to bind a particular property of a component to always use a return value from a function.

For example if you had a label and you wanted to bind it's text to a function which returns a string based on a bindable value, it would be useful in such a case.

Have a look here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7ff3.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7ff2

In the case you have presented above, it's just an event handler and since it's not returning any value (void), I do not see how the binding can really create a benefit here, hence it should not be used.

Moreover your event handler is a static method and as far as I know binding does not work with static methods

Hope this helps.